# Listing unique value counts per groups in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am new to pandas and python.

I am trying to group items by one column and list the information from the data frame per group.

My dataframe:

```
        B          C        D          E              F
1       Honda      USA      2000       Washington     New
2       Honda      USA      2001       Salt Lake      Used
3       Ford       Canada   2005       Washington     New
4       Toyota     USA      2010       Ney York       Used
5       Honda      USA      2001       Salt Lake      Used
6       Honda      Canada   2011       Salt Lake      Crashed
7       Ford       Italy    2014       Rome           New
```

I am trying to group my dataframe by column `B` and list how many `C`, `D`, `E`, `F` column values are in group `B`. For example we see that in column `B` there are 4 `Honda` which I am grouping it together. Then I want to list the following information - `USA(3), Canada(1), 2000(1),2001(2), 2011(1), Washington(1), Salt Lake(3), New(1), Used(2), Crashed(1)` and do the same per every group ( car make ) in column B:

```
        Car         Country        Year        City             Condition
1       Honda(4)    USA(3)         2000(1)     Washington(1)    New(1)
                    Canada(1)      2001(2)     Salt Lake(3)     Used(2)
                                   2011(1)                      Crashed(1)

2       Ford(2)     Canada(1)      2005(5)     Washington(1)    New(2)
                    Italy(1)       2014(1)     Rome(1)

...
```

What I've tried so far:

```
df.groupby(['B'])
```

Which gives me back `<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x11d559080>`

At this point, I am not sure how I should code moving on forward getting the desired results after grouping the column `B`.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need lambda function with custom function for processing each column separately with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and then join values of index to values of counts of `Series` together:

```
def f(x):
    x = x.value_counts()
    y = x.index.astype(str) + '(' + x.astype(str) + ')'
    return y.reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df.groupby(['B']).apply(lambda x: x.apply(f)).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
           B          C        D              E           F
0    Ford(2)   Italy(1)  2014(1)  Washington(1)      New(2)
1        NaN  Canada(1)  2005(1)        Rome(1)         NaN
2   Honda(4)     USA(3)  2001(2)   Salt Lake(3)     Used(2)
3        NaN  Canada(1)  2011(1)  Washington(1)  Crashed(1)
4        NaN        NaN  2000(1)            NaN      New(1)
5  Toyota(1)     USA(1)  2010(1)    Ney York(1)     Used(1)
```

Comment: As always @jezrael, thank you! Not sure if I should ask another question or this is the right place to ask - what if I wanted to group by country and a year so that `C` would have  `USA` with 3 values and `Canada` with 1 value for `Honda` entry?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - I think you need only change `df.groupby(['B'])` to `df.groupby(['B', 'C'])`

Comment: Do you have an idea why would I wont get the same dataframe structure when I try grouping by `Year`? I do not get the same view grouped by a year, I get `Years` listed as expected but `Car model` is simply listed as most_common values?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - Not sure if understand, it is different like `Honda(some number)` ?

Comment: I will post another question with propper dataset, that would make more sense.