# Grouping DataFrame by column and listing its value counts per group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
      ga:country  ga:hostname         ga:pagePathLevel1 ga:pagePathLevel2  ga:keyword      ga:adMatchedQuery          ga:operatingSystem     ga:hour                                    ga:exitPagePath  ga:sessions
0      (not set)  de.google.com       /beste-sms/                 /        +sms            sms Germany best for       Android                09                                        /beste-sms/            1
1      (not set)  de.google.com       /beste-sms/                 /        +sms            sms argentinien            Macintosh              14                                        /beste-sms/            1
2      (not set)  de.google.com       /beste-sms/                 /        +sms            sms skandinav              Android                18                                        /beste-sms/            1
3      (not set)  de.google.com       /beste-sms/                 /        +sms            sms skandinav              Macintosh              20                                        /beste-sms/            1
4      (not set)  de.google.com       /beste-sms/                 /         sms            sms                        iOS                    22                                        /beste-sms/            1
...          ...                     ...               ...               ...         ...                    ...                ...     ...                                                ...          ...
85977      Yemen     google.com         /reviews/         /iphone/        45to54           not set)                   Android                23                                    /reviews/iphone/           1
85978      Yemen     google.com              /tr/        /best-sms/         sms            sms                        Windows                10                                      /tr/best-sms/            1
85979     Zambia     google.com        /best-sms/          /iphone/        +best +sms      (not set)                  Android                16                                  /best-sms/iphone/            1
85980   Zimbabwe     google.com         /reviews/         /testsms/        test            test                       Windows                22                                  /reviews/testsms/            1
85981   Zimbabwe     google.com         /reviews/         /testsms/        testsms         testsms                    Windows                23                                  /reviews/testsms/            1
```

I would like to group them by column `ga:adMatchedQuery` and get counts of each column values for each group in `ga:adMatchedQuery`

This question is a follow up on [this question which may provide more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542245/listing-unique-value-counts-per-groups-in-pandas-dataframe/59542349#59542349) of what I am trying to achieve.

After using the same code structure as @jezrael suggested:

```
def f(x):
    x = x.value_counts()
    y = x.index.astype(str) + ' (' + x.astype(str) + ')'
    return y.reset_index(drop=True)


df = df.groupby(['ga:adMatchedQuery']).apply(lambda x: x.apply(f))
print(df)
```

I get this result:

```
ga:country             ga:hostname           ga:pagePathLevel1    ga:pagePathLevel2        ga:keyword            ga:adMatchedQuery  ga:operatingSystem    ga:hour   ga:exitPagePath ga:sessions
United States(5683)    google.com(14924)    /us/(4187)            /best-sms/(4565)         Undetermined(1855)   (not set)(15327)    Windows(7616)         18(806)   /reviews/testsms/(1880) 1(14005)
United Kingdom(1691)   zh.google.com(170)   /reviews/(4093)       /testsms/(3561)          free sms(1729)                           Android(4291)         20(805)   /reviews/scandina/(1307)    2(815)
Canada(1201)           t.google.com(80)     /best-sms/(2169)      /free-sms/(2344)         +sms(1414)                               iOS(2136)             19(804)   /best-sms/(1291)    3(231)
Indonesia(445)         es.google.com(33)    /coupons/(1264)       /scandina/(1751)         +free +sms(1008)                         Macintosh(978)        17(787)   /coupons/testsms/holiday-deal/(760) 4(92)
Hong Kong(443)         pl.google.com(33)    /uk/(1172)            /(1508)                  25to34(988)                              Linux(160)            21(779)   /coupons/scandina/holiday-deal/(239)    6(40)
Australia(353)         fr.google.com(27)    /ca/(886)             /windows/(365)           best sms(803)                            Chrome OS(73)         16(766)   (not set)(112)  5(38)
```

Whereas I am trying to achieve this:

```
ga:adMatchedQuery    ga:country               ga:hostname
Undetermined(1855)   United States(100)       google.com(1000)
                     United Kingdom(200)      zh.google.com(12)

free sms(1855)       United States(100)       google.com(1000)
                     United Kingdom(200)      zh.google.com(12)

...
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is only changed order of columns, you can use before my solution:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['ga:adMatchedQuery'], sort=False).tolist()   
df = df[['ga:adMatchedQuery'] + cols]
```

Sample with data from previous answer:

Here is data grouped by `F` column, order of columns names is not changed:

```
def f(x):
    x = x.value_counts()
    y = x.index.astype(str) + '(' + x.astype(str) + ')'
    return y.reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df.groupby(['F']).apply(lambda x: x.apply(f)).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
          B          C        D              E           F
0   Honda(1)  Canada(1)  2011(1)   Salt Lake(1)  Crashed(1)
1    Ford(2)   Italy(1)  2014(1)  Washington(2)      New(3)
2   Honda(1)  Canada(1)  2005(1)        Rome(1)         NaN
3        NaN     USA(1)  2000(1)            NaN         NaN
4   Honda(2)     USA(3)  2001(2)   Salt Lake(2)     Used(3)
5  Toyota(1)        NaN  2010(1)    Ney York(1)         NaN
```

Columns names are changed:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['F'], sort=False).tolist()
df = df[['F'] + cols]
print (df)
         F       B       C     D           E
1      New   Honda     USA  2000  Washington
2     Used   Honda     USA  2001   Salt Lake
3      New    Ford  Canada  2005  Washington
4     Used  Toyota     USA  2010    Ney York
5     Used   Honda     USA  2001   Salt Lake
6  Crashed   Honda  Canada  2011   Salt Lake
7      New    Ford   Italy  2014        Rome

def f(x):
    x = x.value_counts()
    y = x.index.astype(str) + '(' + x.astype(str) + ')'
    return y.reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df.groupby(['F']).apply(lambda x: x.apply(f)).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
            F          B          C        D              E
0  Crashed(1)   Honda(1)  Canada(1)  2011(1)   Salt Lake(1)
1      New(3)    Ford(2)   Italy(1)  2014(1)  Washington(2)
2         NaN   Honda(1)  Canada(1)  2005(1)        Rome(1)
3         NaN        NaN     USA(1)  2000(1)            NaN
4     Used(3)   Honda(2)     USA(3)  2001(2)   Salt Lake(2)
5         NaN  Toyota(1)        NaN  2010(1)    Ney York(1)
```

Comment: Trying this out. So when using group by it is important that the column that I want to group by is first if I want to explode the values from other columns based on the group?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - I think here is special kind of groupby because groupbing column is not used finally, is removed by `reset_index(drop=True)`. So order of columns is same like original. If need another order is necessary change it like this solution